# Is it possible to include the same few lines of scenario at the beginning of a new one?

Tags: behat, gherkin

I have a 138 tests long scenario that allows me to test if a workflow works as it should.

However, I'm not a huge fan of having to repeat the same 6 lines that allows me to log in as an administrator, which are:

```
Given I am on "user/login"
And I fill in "admin@admin.com" for "name"
And I fill in "admin" for "pass"
And I press "Log in"
Then I should get a "200" HTTP response
And I should see "Dashboard"
```

I repeat this part 6 times so far, and I'm planning on needing to add this a few more time for some other tests.

So my question is the following: is there a way, through the FeatureContext file or any other way, to make these lines repeat?

Thank you in advance

---

So this is how I did:

Instead of calling Gherkin sentence one after the other, I parsed the `vendor/` directory to find examples of how sentences where made.

my function to that connects me looks like the following:

```
/**
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws Exception
 * @Given I am the administrator
 */
public function iAmTheAdministrator(){

  $this->visitPath('/user/login');
  $element = $this->getSession()->getPage();
  $element->fillField('name', 'admin@admin.com');
  $element->fillField('pass', 'admin');
  $element->pressButton("Se connecter");
  $this->assertSession()->pageTextContains('Dashboard');
}
```

This is pretty straight forward, and works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways I know of that repeats steps. One is with background steps and the other involves running snippets of steps.

Background steps run at the start of each scenario.

```
Background:
    Given I have done this
    And this other thing

Scenario: Do stuff
    When I do this
    Then stuff should happen
```

This only works if all tests have the same starting procedure...

Snippets run whenever you call them which I assume you would rather want

```
Given I have logged in as an administrator
```

Step definition:

```
Given(/^I have logged in as an administrator$/) do
    steps %{
    Given I am on "user/login"
    And I fill in "admin@admin.com" for "name"
    And I fill in "admin" for "pass"
    And I press "Log in"
    Then I should get a "200" HTTP response
    And I should see "Dashboard"
    }
end
```

This allows you to use only one step which you can call at any time to run multiple steps

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you mean I can create a function with the FeatureContext file that returns the steps? Like, all I need to do is to "return" an array with the steps I need?

Comment: Wherever your step definitions are put it there. You're basically making one step do multiple things as if it was a function per say.

Comment: I updated my quesiton, it almost works but it seems that something's wrong

Comment: It seems that since Behat 3.x it's not longer possible to do what you're suggesting, but I found another way (will edit my question when I get it to work)

You still put me on the right track so thank you :)

Comment: Awesome. No problem. Good luck with your testing